# Dialing a miniaturized stargate

Tags: microcontroller, stepper-motor, encoder

I want to build a miniaturized Stargate but I have no clue regarding the electronic part.  The Stargate is a fixed circle with 9 chevrons (see links bellow). An inner circle is spinning inside the main circle and has on it 38 symbols. Let's say someone presses on a symbol on DHD device (see links bellow). Now the upper chevron needs to identify that symbol during the circle's spin, and stop the motor.
The question is how can that be accomplished? I guess a laser reading is to complicated. Is it possible that the inner circle (the one that it is spinning) to have inside one coil for each symbol, and then the chevron to induce a current in each coil during spinning of the circle, and read the value?
Disclaimer: I know almost nothing about electronics and english is not my native language.

Many people might not know what a Stargate is so I put some links.

Dialing a Stargate: http://youtu.be/Qidw0Qqu8h0
DHD: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate_(device)#Dial-Home_Device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate_%28device%29#Dial-Home_Device)

Comment: How exactly are you planning on making the whole "wormhole" aspect of the stargate work? Or do you want to build a *model* of a stargate, rather then a functional one (also, if you know how to build a *real* stargate, can I help you sell it to $GOVERNMENT)?

Comment: You could take the easy option and make a Pegusus galaxy one, they just light up instead of spinning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention how big you want this to be, and that matters. Another important question is if you want the gate to be open in the center, so you can pass something through it (only when the gate is off, of course.)
A stepper / microcontroller is the obvious way to go, but there are a few other things to think about.

1. For a simple system, you need some way to detect zero degrees rotation, called an index. This can be just an LED / photosensor with a way to block the path between them at one point. After you get an index signal, you know where you are and can then count steps to tell where you've moved to. The problem with this is that, when you turn on the system you don't know where it is, and have to step the motor until you get an index signal.
2. If you don't want a power-on hunt, you have to use a more sophisticated (and expensive) encoder.
3. A stepper is really handy, because you get a known angle change per step. The drawback to this is that you can't get really smooth low-speed rotation, such as when the wheel stops. Standard steppers will do 200 or 400 steps per rotation. If this is not OK, there are two ways to handle this. The first is to cut the angle per step using a microstepper. You're on your own here. The other is to put a reduction gear of some sort between the ring and the motor.
4. Fortunately (or unfortunately, depending on how easy you want this), you'll need to use some sort of indirect drive if you want the center of the ring to be open. With the center of the ring open, you can't just put the motor shaft at the center of a disk with the ring painted on. The obvious way to drive a ring is with a rubber wheel on the motor shaft which contacts either the inner or outer edge of the ring. (Do it down in the base of the gate.)This is fortunate because the rubber wheel will be smaller than the ring, so you get smoother rotation. This is unfortunate, because the ratio of ring motion to shaft motion is hard to measure "exactly" and will change with time as the wheel wears. Not only that, you can expect a certain amount of slippage, particularly when you start and stop the ring. This also means that if you use an encoder on the motor shaft it may not exactly tell you what the wheel is doing. I'd recommend two set of index sensors. One sensor tells you when ANY of the 38 symbols is lined up exactly, and the other tells you that symbol 0 is lined up. That way, you can get a perfect alignment when you stop the ring.
5. If you go to a simple disk for the ring, you may need to reconsider the number of symbols. Since a stepper has a fixed number of steps, you'll need to have a number of symbols which produces an integral number of steps per symbol. For instance, with a 200 step motor, a 38-symbol ring will need (200/38), or 5.26 steps to move from one symbol to the next, and it can't do this. In this case, you'd probably want to use 40 symbols.
6. If your gate gets to any size, you'll need to be careful about how fast you try to accelerate or decelerate it. Basically, the ring will tend to lag behind the commanded position or try to overshoot it, since it takes a bit to speed up or slow down, and if the lag gets too great, like the equivalent of two steps, the stepper will "slip" and you'll find yourself with a 4-step error between where the ring is and where you think it is.

Comment: good thing you pointed out some technical problems that may occur; now I see that the diameter and weight matters. Yes, i want the gate/circle to be open like in the linked video. The diameter I think would be 10 - 15 cm. The motor will be inside the ramp. Regarding the problem with the steps per symbol, I think I can use a gear on the motor's shaft with a calculated diameter (this will be "fun"). No, I won't use a rubber band for spinning but a gear placed outside the inner circle and it will not be visible.

Comment: can I use only a regular DC motor and an optical controller? That way I have more control over the rotation. I'm learning as I go; hope i don't talk nonsense.

Comment: Yup. It will give you better angular resolution, but the setup will cost a good deal more.  Sensing position by a gear on the motor shaft is NOT a good idea for two reasons. First, an optical controller for the motor will already use an encoder on the shaft, and the controller will send that info to you. Second, accumulated slippage will be a real problem. If the ring doesn't exactly line up with the chevron when it flashes, it's going to look really cheap.

Comment: A few other thoughts - 1) Using gears to drive the ring is a good idea but (big but) you'll need to make a very precise mount for the ring so as to get the teeth to mesh smoothly and quietly. Probably you'd use 2 small gears, one for the motor and the other as an idler. The ring could be made from commercially available 5" gear with a large, like 4", hole machined out of the center. The ring would sit on the two small gears. I suggested a rubber wheel just because fabrication would be easy and you'd get smooth, quiet motion.

Answer (score 3):

Fun project :)

The scope of this question is larger than can be answered here, but I'll give a few pointers to start you out.

You don't want to try to read the symbol electronically.  Instead, you want your system to be aware of the orientation of the rotating ring, and then stop the motor at the appropriate time.

A good way to do this would be to use a stepper motor.  Driving a stepper is not trivial, but it may be entertaining to figure it out.  Basically, you tell the stepper controller exactly how much to move, and then it stops the motor at the appropriate time.

An easier way, although less accurate, would be to place some sort of conducting contacts along the ring.  Imagine that you have two stationary contacts somewhere along the main (non-moving) ring.  Then you would put 38 copper disks (for example) evenly spaced along the inner ring, so that they close the contacts when the disk is spinning.  This way, by counting the contact closures, you could know which symbol is closest to the top...

Either of these methods will require a microcontroller to orchestrate things.

Sorry that I'm not going into more detail, but hopefully this will help!  My wife says that she'll buy one from you if you decide to sell them :)

Oh, and your English is impeccable!  Even if it wasn't, there's no need to apologize.

Good luck!

Comment: Tank you, your answer gave me some clues. Expanding the idea with copper disks - wouldn't be cheaper than a stepper motor, to put a divided copper disk on the spinning circle and for each symbol to place a resistor with different values for the chevron to read. So if on the DHD a symbol has x ohm so would be on the circle.

Comment: so your wife is a Stargate fan :) ? I need to pay an electronist to help me with this but I need to know an estimative cost. In the meantime I make the parts in CAD and if I'm successful I will sell it - with a discount for you.

Comment: @ILiviu That is a good idea, but I think you would have problems with implementing it.  To be able to detect the resistor value you would need to do some analog-to-digital conversions.  But, with moving contacts sliding over each other, you won't get a solid signal on which to perform the conversion.  I still think that you should keep track of the ring position and stop the motor when you know the symbol should be in the right place...  There may be better solutions out there, though.  Perhaps someone will suggest a different method here? And yes, we both enjoyed SG :)

Comment: An optical encoder might be a good bet.

Answer (score 3):

Simple low tech answer. Cogs. And Gears. Make the inner circle have small cog notches. Since the outside of the circle will be hidden by the outer chevron ring, it will not be seen. The inner circle cogs sit on a matching cog/gear on a servo motor. Since you know how many cogs to move the ring in position, the rest is simple to control. The servo would hide in the pedastle/ramp. There are some small servos out there. Tiny!

Example: [image]

[Some guys doing the same thing you want to do.](http://hackaday.io/project/596/logs)

Answer (score 2):

An optical encoder, a stepper motor and a microcontroller are the *right* answer.  Your biggest problem may well be that you will need a graphical display of reasonable brightness and resolution (16x16 would be the minimum, higher res would be better) to display the symbols in the chevrons.

You would also need a microcontroller in the DHD to control the illumination of each symbol as it is pressed and locked, and a communications link (hardwired is easiest and most reliable, but wireless is entirely possible) to the gate.

I can't offer anything on getting the wavefront of the wormhole to explode out of the gate, let alone getting the wormhole to open, sorry :( you'll need to speak to the Ancients for that...

Comment: I think now that would be much more cost-effective to use only a stepper motor and microcontroller. The chevrons don't have any symbols on them - they just light up and expand when activated (see the video in the link). I want to replicate the Stargate and DHD from SG1 - I don't remember the ones from Atlantis. For the wormhole I thought about using some laser and optical glass around the inner ring, in case the ancients don't have an account to answer.

Comment: Your thinking SGU. SG1 only had glowy orange/red lights in the chevrons. SGA had blue ligts.